# Symmetric polynomials with Vieta's and Newton's theorems

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $ x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$  be the solutions of the equation $ x^3 -3x^2 + x - 1 = 0.$
>
> Determine the values of $$\frac{1}{{x_{1}x_{2}}} + \frac{1}{{x_{2}x_{3}}} + \frac{1}{{x_{3}x_{1}}}$$
>
> and also
>
> $$ x_{1}^{3}+x_{2}^{3}+x_{3}^{3}$$

Comment: hint: the sum is given by $$x_1+x_2+x_3=3$$

Comment: Would that mean that the product of all three is 1?

Comment: it is the formula of Vieta!

Comment: Did you mean $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$ are the solutions instead of $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}$ is one of the solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Given $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=x^3-3x^2+x-1$, the elementary symmetric polynomials of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are given by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas):
$$ e_1=x_1+x_2+x_3=3,\quad e_2=x_1 x_2+x_1 x_3+x_2 x_3 = 1,\quad e_3=x_1 x_2 x_3 = 1 \tag{1}$$
hence
$$ \frac{1}{x_1 x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1 x_3}+\frac{1}{x_2 x_3} = \frac{e_1}{e_3} = \color{red}{3}.\tag{2}$$
Given the elementary symmetric polynomials, the power sums are given by [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities):
$$ p_1=x_1+x_2+x_3 = 3,\quad p_2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=e_1^2-2e_2 = 7,\tag{3} $$
and since $x_j^3 = 3x_j^2-x_j+1$ for every $j\in\{1,2,3\}$,
$$ p_3 = 3p_2-p_1+3 = 21-3+3 = \color{red}{21}.\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

For the first case, using Vieta's Formula $$x_1x_2x_3=1\implies\dfrac1{x_1x_2}=x_3$$

For the second,

**Method$\#1$:** observe that $$x_r^3-3x_r^2+x_r-1=0\implies x_r^3=3x_r^2-x_r+1\ \ \ \ (r)$$ for $r=1,2,3$

$(1)+(2)+(3)=?$

Now $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+2(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)$

**Method$\#2$:**

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)$$

Comment: Wait so how would the last step help me find the sum of the solutions cubed?

Comment: @differentialequation, What is $(1)+(2)+(3)?$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$x^3-3x^2+x-1=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$$
so by developing  the RHS we see that $\sum x_i x_j=1:$ the coefficient of $x$ and similarly  $x_1x_2x_3=1$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$.
Denote $V_1$ the first desired value than $V_1\times(x_1x_2x_3)=x_1+x_2+x_3$. And denote $V_2$ the second value then

$$(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3=V_2+3(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)(x_1+x_2+x_3)-3x_1x_2x_3$$